# "ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" was auto added in my /etc/sudoers file. Is this a Security Breach?

Tags: security, sudo

> **`ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`** line was **auto added twice** at the end of my `/etc/sudoers` file.

- My linux suddenly stopped asking for a password every time I ran a sudo command. This made me investigate the issue.
- Even after running `sudo -k` to reset the grace time it would not ask for my password.
- I figured out the meaning of that line and commented out the 2 lines to fix the issue and things were back to normal.

  > But as per my searches the sudoers file is only **edited manually** and no way I could have given ALL users NOPASSWD permissions to ALL commands. 
  >   **Could this mean that a script I executed changed the sudoers file? Is this a cause of concern?**

OS : Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon

Comment: Whoever, or whatever, added that line to `sudoers` needed to have root privileges to do so.

Comment: That's certainly a cause of concern. Can you tie in the last modification time of /etc/sudoers to some event (in logs or modification times of some other files)

Comment: Long shot, but does `sudo grep -rl 'NOPASSWD:ALL' /etc /lib /usr /var /home /root` return anything other than /etc/sudoers?

Comment: @roaima will surely try that.

Comment: @roaima `sudo grep -rl 'NOPASSWD:ALL' /etc /lib /usr /var /home /root` has returned the following as of now: `/etc/sudoers
/usr/lib/snapd/snapd
/var/log/auth.log
`

Comment: @roaima Oh wait ! `grep` has also returned `/home/neon/HUAWEI-4g_Dongle/Linux/install`. I think I've found the issue. I had run the **install** script for the **HUAWEI 4g dongle** [https://pastebin.com/e37GGKsu](https://pastebin.com/e37GGKsu). Its most likely happened through this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After running this command

```
sudo grep -rl 'NOPASSWD:ALL' /etc /lib /usr /var /home /root
```

you advised that several files matched:

```
/etc/sudoers
/usr/lib/snapd/snapd
/var/log/auth.log
/home/neon/HUAWEI-4g_Dongle/Linux/install
```

The first three of these files could be reasonably expected to contain a match, and can be safely ignored. The fourth, on the other hand, appears to be a possible culprit and bears further investigation.

Indeed, your [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/e37GGKsu) shows these snippets:

```
SOFTWARENAME="Mobile Partner"
SOFTWARENAME=$(echo $SOFTWARENAME | sed s\#\ \#_\#g)
TEMPFILE="${SOFTWARENAME}_install_$PPID"
... 

grep -v "MobilePartner.sh" /etc/sudoers >/tmp/${TEMPFILE} 2>&1
echo -e "ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /tmp/${TEMPFILE}
...

cp -f /tmp/${TEMPFILE} /etc/sudoers
```

Yes, I would say that's a (terrible) security hole from fairly lousy quality code.

Having removed (or commented out) the lines from your `/etc/sudoers` file, I would also recommend you check the permissions on that file. They should be `ug=r,o=` (`0440` = `r--r-----`), probably owned by `root`:`root`.

Comment: Verified the file permissions to be `0440`. Seems like it was a really bad install script that came bundled with the dongle. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Wow, good idea for grep 'NOPASSWD:ALL' /etc /lib /usr /var /home /root !