# In sudoers does (ALL)=All refer to users or privileges? User Privilege Managment

Tags: permissions, sudo, access-control

Considering how getting this wrong is extremely dangerous, I feel it deserves an explicit answer. There are many other answers concerning the use of ALL in sudoers, but they do not directly answer this question:

Does ALL refer to users in a group ; Does ALL refer to access to Cmnd_Alias[es] ; OR Can it refer to either and both depending on where it is located in the line?

For instance: 
a group like `REGULARUSER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN` would mean `ALL` users in group `REGULARUSER` have access privleges to `Cmnd_Alias` `SHUTDOWN`.

In other words the syntax is: `Group \ Users \ Command Permission Specifications.` Is this correct?

So that means I can use `ALL` in instances like root to grant all privileges to all users in the group, hence the   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL of user group `root`

Some other questions about the use of `ALL`

[Trying to understand the difference between "modernNeo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" and "modernNeo ALL=(ALL) ALL" in the sudoers file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490835/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-modernneo-all-allall-all-and-m)

["ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" was auto added in my /etc/sudoers file. Is this a Security Breach?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462957/all-all-all-nopasswdall-was-auto-added-in-my-etc-sudoers-file-is-this-a-s)

Answer (score 1):

From [the manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Other_special_characters_and_reserved_words):

> The reserved word **ALL** is a built-in *alias* that always causes a
>   match to succeed. It can be used wherever one might otherwise use a
>   `Cmnd_Alias`, `User_Alias`, `Runas_Alias`, or `Host_Alias`.

So, depending on the context, it can be all commands, all users or groups, all users or groups, or all hosts.

> For instance: a group like `REGULARUSER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN` would mean `ALL` users in group `REGULARUSER` have access privleges to `Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN`.

Yes, but "all users" isn't because of any `ALL` present in the rule. The first `ALL` is for the `Host_Alias`, and the second `ALL` is for the `Runas_Alias`. It's because the [`User_List` and `Runas_List` can include groups](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Aliases):

> A `User_List` is made up of one or more user names, user IDs (prefixed with ‘`#`’), system group names and IDs (prefixed with ‘`%`’ and ‘`%#`’ respectively), netgroups (prefixed with ‘`+`’), non-Unix group names and IDs (prefixed with ‘`%:`’ and ‘`%:#`’ respectively) and `User_Aliases`.

And:

> A `Runas_List` is similar to a `User_List` except that instead of `User_Aliases` it can contain `Runas_Aliases`.

And when the `User_list` includes a group, it means all members of that group, unless you exclude specific members by negation.

> In other words the syntax is: `Group \ Users \ Command Permission Specifications`.

Not at all. See [the manpage for EBNF description of the  grammar](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#User_specification), but roughly it is:

```
<user_list> <host_list> = (<runas_list>) <tags> <commands>
```

Or, from the manpage:

> The basic structure of a user specification is “who where = (as_whom)
>   what”.